# How many houses can I buy?

Tags: forza-horizon-4

So far I have found a purchased two houses, one near the festival and one on the coast.

How many purchasable properties are available for me to buy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple houses / residents to buy.

From what I can find on google there are about 12 houses/castles.

Here is the full list as acquired from [this site](https://www.windowscentral.com/forza-horizon-4-houses):

- **Edinburgh Castle**:

  Located in the heart of the city, Edinburgh Castle offers the best of Horizon's properties

  15,000,000 CR.
- **Bamburgh Castle**:

  This historical home overlooks Forza Horizon 4's coast, situated alongside the long east-facing beach.

  10,000,000 CR.
- **Lake Lodge**:

  If castles aren't for you, Lake Lodge is a top-tier lakeside house, overlooking Derwentwater.

  5,000,000 CR. (Free for VIP Pass owners)
- **Fairlawn Manor**:

  Fairlawn Manor is a bold stately home located in the map center, positioned among the upper-class Forza Horizon 4 homes

  2,000,000 CR.
- **Derwent Mansion**:

  Found on the west side of Derwentwater, this lakeside property is a cheaper alternative to Lake Lodge.

  1,500,000 CR.
- **Castleview Road**:

  Found in the southern suburbs of Edinburgh, this offers just a quick drive to the city center

  750,000 CR.
- **The Huntsman Lodge**:

  Hidden deep into Lakehurst Forest, this house keeps you far away from the busy roads of Horizon

  750,000 CR.
- **Thatch Corner**:

  This cozy beachside thatched cottage is another quiet retreat from the action.

  500,000 CR.
- **Kingfisher Cottage**:

  Located beside the Derwentwater reservoir, this historical cottage is tucked just off the roadside.

  350,000 CR.
- **Croftdale Farm**:

  Take in the Scottish Highlands with this sky-high property, hidden near Glen Rannoch in the north-west corner of the map.

  200,000 CR.
- **Sunflower Meadows**:

  This white semi-detached cottage is found in Ambleside, offering another excellent option for first-time buyers

  200,000 CR.
- **The Gables**:

  In an unlikely turn of events, The Gables is a property gifted by film makers after your work as a movie stunt driver.

  Best of all, this location is entirely free.

Comment: In total, that will be 36,250,000 cr (or 31,250,000 cr for VIP members). Word to the wise! If you get the VIP pass _after_ spending 5,000,000 on the Lake Lodge, _you will not get the money back_. I literally paid the price learning the hard way.